# Firewall rule configuration in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I have following terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = "test" # Replace with your project ID
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-a"
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "example_subnet" {
  name          = "example-subnet2"      # Replace with your subnet name
  region        = "us-central1"          # Replace with your desired region
  network       = "default"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.100.0.0/29"         # Replace with your desired CIDR block
}


# Service Account
# name = “gke-sa@agatest.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id   = "gke-sa"
  display_name = "Service Account"
}

# Role binding
# resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "admin-account-iam" {
#  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account.name
#  role               = "roles/container.nodeServiceAgent"
#}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "my-builder-container-nodeServiceAgent" {
  project = "test"
  role    = "roles/container.nodeServiceAgent"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
}

# Egress rule
resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
  direction = "EGRESS"
  name      = "new-firewall-rule"
  network   = "default"
    
  deny {
    protocol = "all"
  }
    
  destination_ranges  = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  disabled            = "false"

  log_config {
    metadata = "EXCLUDE_ALL_METADATA"
  }

  priority                = "100"
  target_service_accounts = [google_service_account.service_account.name]
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name     = "my-gke-cluster16"
  location = "us-central1-a"
  network            = "default"
  subnetwork         = google_compute_subnetwork.example_subnet.name  # Specify the subnetwork here


  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count      = 1

  node_config {
    machine_type = "n1-standard-2"
    disk_size_gb = 100
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_preemptible_nodes" {
  name       = "my-node-pool"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.my_cluster.id
  node_count = 1

  node_config {
    machine_type = "e2-micro"
    service_account = google_service_account.service_account.email
  }

  autoscaling {
    min_node_count = 1
    max_node_count = 6
  }
}
```

When I’m checking the Firewall rule in UI and the “Applicable to instances”, I can’t see any instances. I should see there instances created for the GKE cluster. Why is that?

Moreover I can see that deployment print this error:

```
Error: Request `Create IAM Members roles/container.nodeServiceAgent serviceAccount:gke-ctf-sa@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com for project "test"` returned error: Error applying IAM policy for project "test": Error setting IAM policy for project "test": googleapi: Error 403: Policy update access denied., forbidden


Step #4: │   with module.client_module.google_project_iam_member.my-builder-container-nodeServiceAgent,
Step #4: │   on module/disablesa.tf line 37, in resource "google_project_iam_member" "my-builder-container-nodeServiceAgent":
Step #4: │   37: resource "google_project_iam_member" "my-builder-container-nodeServiceAgent" {
Step #4: │
```